# make a query in sql as to get all list of rows with where condition

Tags: sql

i have following table and need to get the all rows and the condition end_dt IS NULL OR end_dt >=CURRENT DATE has to apply only for the rows  where PLAN_ID is EPTONDEL1.

Input table:
[image]

Output should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXxfx.png)

Comment: For important details on how to improve your question see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I gave an answer where I have interpreted your question, could be a language barrier, but by changing the order of the conditions it might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if I understand your question...
You want ALL rows where PLAN_ID='STARTTEST1' but rows where PLAN_ID='EPTONDEL1' should only show when end_dt IS NULL OR end_dt >=CURRENT DATE

Rearranging some logic and doing nesting logic gives you this

```
select * from table where PLAN_ID='STARTEST1' 
OR (
PLAN_ID='EPTONDEL1' AND (end_dt IS NULL OR end_dt >=CURRENT DATE) 
)
```

This should give you the desired result (if I understood correclty) :)

Alright changing the query after your comment to give you ALL records except EPTONDEL1, except where the condition is set...

```
select * from table where PLAN_ID<>'EPTONDEL1' 
OR (
PLAN_ID='EPTONDEL1' AND (end_dt IS NULL OR end_dt >=CURRENT DATE) 
)
```

Above gives you all records, and add the extra check only to EPTONDEL1.

Comment: sorry , i need all the records and the condition  end_dt IS NULL OR end_dt >=CURRENT DATE has to apply for the record of PLAN_ID='EPTONDEL1' only